# Crystal Reports: Subreport on more than one page

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

Hi I have a Crystal reports, report set up and I want to insert a sub report as the first page.  I thought I can do this buy placing a subreport in the PageHeader of my other report.  It works well but it does not display the rest of my sub report pages; it only displays the first page.  Can someone help me configure this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a subreport in the pageheader and the subreport is longer than a page, crystal might blow up!